# uso de CASE en visual basic para hacer una consulta sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

Realizando un tutorial de sql con el uso de **case**, lo vi en este [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/) me saltó la duda de cómo se realizaría pero en *visual studio*.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
Dim Ingresos = From p In Terra.Det_DocumentosIngreso
    Join m In Terra.Mae_DocumentosIngreso On p.Num_CorrelativoInterno Equals m.Num_CorrelativoInterno And p.Cod_Doc Equals m.Cod_Doc
    Join n In Terra.Mae_Articulos On p.Cod_Art Equals n.Cod_Art
    Where p.Cod_Art = dArticulo.Datos.Cod_ArtDocumental And
    (case n.Cod_Uni_Con
        when 1 then FLOOR(p.Num_Cantidad - p.Num_Cantidad_Descuento - p.Num_Cantidad_Linea)) > 0
```

Y mi consulta en SQL es:

```
FROM det_documentosingreso a inner join
mae_documentosingreso b on a.Num_CorrelativoInterno = b.Num_CorrelativoInterno and a.Cod_Doc = b.Cod_Doc inner join
mae_articulos c on a.cod_art = c.cod_art
WHERE --(a.Num_Cantidad - (a.Num_Cantidad_Descuento + a.Num_Cantidad_Linea)) > 0
(case c.Cod_Uni_Con
when 1 then FLOOR(a.Num_Cantidad - (a.Num_Cantidad_Descuento + a.Num_Cantidad_Linea))
else (a.Num_Cantidad - (a.Num_Cantidad_Descuento + a.Num_Cantidad_Linea))
end) > 0
AND a.Cod_Art = @Cod_Art
AND a.Num_CorrelativoInterno = b.Num_CorrelativoInterno
AND a.Cod_Doc = b.Cod_Doc
AND b.Num_CorrelativoVisacion > 0
AND a.cod_bodega = @Oficina
ORDER BY b.Fec_Solicitud,Num_CorrelativoVisacion,b.num_correlativointerno, a.Numero_Item ASC
```

Pero aparentemente donde tengo el **where** (en mi consulta hecha en visual basic) me lo toma como un *Error de sintaxis*

Alguien sabe cómo se utiliza esta expresión en visual basic?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score -1):

En principio lo que veo que intentas hacer es usar LINQ en .NET. LINQ es un tanto limitado en cuanto a las expresiones SQL que te permite crear, en particular creo que no es posible crear un CASE como intentas.

De todas formas te sugiero comenzar por revisar la documentación de LINQ para que entiendas mejor como funciona.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq

Comment: ok, voy a leer la documentación, existe alguna alternativa?

Comment: Para ejecutar consultas SQL si, por ejemplo podrías usar un SQLDataAdapter para conectarte a la base de datos y ejecutar tu query tal cual corre en SQL, pero obtendrías los datos a través de DataSets.

Comment: Favor de leer [answer], pues responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad